# Data reloading - UICollectionView - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, reloaddata

I don't know what happens, but calling reloadData on the collection view causes nothing. Nothing happens. Maybe I'm missing something, I just don't know what.

I've tried with data on launch and it worked, the collection view was populated. But fetching remote data and then calling reloadData afterwards is not populating the collection view.

Thank you in advance

Class is below:

FoodChannelsCollection.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "YouTubeDataAPI.h"

@interface FoodChannelsCollection: UIViewController <YouTubeDataAPIDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource>

@end
```

FoodChannelsCollection.m

```
#import "FoodChannelsCollection.h"
#import "ChannelCell.h"
#import "UIImageView+ImageLoader.h"

@interface FoodChannelsCollection()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;

@end

@implementation FoodChannelsCollection

//@synthesize collectionView;

NSMutableArray *channels;

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------//
// MARK: Controller's main view setup
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------//

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    channels = [NSMutableArray new];

    YouTubeDataAPI *dataApi = [YouTubeDataAPI getInstance];
    dataApi.delegate = self;
    [dataApi fetchFirstChannelsBatch];
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------//
// MARK: YouTubeDataAPIDelegate
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------//

- (void)getFirstChannelsBatch:(NSArray *)firstChannelsBatch
{
    if (firstChannelsBatch == nil) { return; }

    NSLog(@"firstChannelsBatch count: %i", [firstChannelsBatch count]);

    if ([firstChannelsBatch count] == 0) { return; }

    NSLog(@"firstChannelsBatch count(2): %i", [firstChannelsBatch count]);

    [channels addObjectsFromArray: firstChannelsBatch];

    NSLog(@"Channels count (Del): %i", [channels count]);

    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------//
// MARK: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------//

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;

    return CGSizeMake(width/2, width/2);
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0;
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------//
// MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------//

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(nonnull UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"Channels count: %i", [channels count]);

    return [channels count];
    //return 8;
}

- (nonnull __kindof UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(nonnull UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Channel *channel = channels[indexPath.row];

    ChannelCell *cell = (ChannelCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier: @"ChannelCell" forIndexPath: indexPath];
    [cell.thumbnail setImageWithUrl: channel.thumbnailUrl];
    [cell.channelTitle setText: channel.channelTitle];
    //[cell.channelTitle setText: @"Test Cell"];

    return cell;
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------//
// MARK: Memory Warning
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------//

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

Comment: Two things: When you do `[self.collectionView reloadData];`, is `channels` empty? Also, are you in Main Thread at this moment? Meaning just before `NSLog("Main Thread: %d", [NSThread isMainThread])` prints what exactly?

Comment: Do you make `FoodChannelsCollection` `delegate` and `dataSource` of `collectionView`? I don't see code like
`self.collectionView.delegate = self`

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for answering: I am on Main Thread, I set Delegate and Data Source in Storyboard. My logs: 2018-07-13 09:25:04.912570+0100 Foodly[91603:4517301] Channels count: 0
2018-07-13 09:25:05.465092+0100 Foodly[91603:4517301] Is Main Thread
2018-07-13 09:25:05.465249+0100 Foodly[91603:4517301] firstChannelsBatch count: 50
2018-07-13 09:25:05.465377+0100 Foodly[91603:4517301] firstChannelsBatch count(2): 50
2018-07-13 09:25:05.465482+0100 Foodly[91603:4517301] Channels count (Del): 50.      I'm using AFNetworking for fetching remote data.

Comment: Never mind, problem solved, it was the silliest thing. Thanks guys.